# Criterion for $PSL(2,q)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, simple-groups, linear-groups

I am looking for a criterion for a group to be isomorphic to $PSL(2,p^k)$ in terms of its Sylow $p$-subgroups.

For example, let $G$ be finite group of order $p^km$ where $p$ is an odd prime not dividing $m$.
Suppose that

- $G$ is simple.
- Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are elementary abelian.
- Any two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ intersect trivially.
- $G$ has exactly $p^k+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Do these conditions imply that $G\cong PSL(2,p^k)$? (Presumably, such an isomorphism would be proved by treating the $p^k+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups as the $p^k+1$ points of projective space).

Is there similar set of conditions that implies that $G\cong PSL(2,p^k)$?

Comment: The third and fourth conditions that I gave imply that $G$ acts doubly transitively on its Sylow $p$-subgroups. Maybe there is a way to force $G$ to act sharply triply transitively and from there to get an isomorphism with $PSL(2,p^k)$.

Comment: The answer to your question is certainly yes, and can be proved by using the classification of doubly transitive groups, but that uses the classification of finite simple groups. It is possible that you can deduce it from one of the pre-classification theorem, but you would still be using big results. By the way, ${\rm PSL}(2,p^k)$ does not act triply transitively for $p$ odd - the 2-point stabilizer has two orbits of size $(p^k-1)/2$. The group ${\rm PGL}(2,p^k)$ acts triply transitively.